# Writing output of dex2jar to other folder

Tags: java, batch-file, apk, decompiling, dex2jar

I am trying to write a batch file that writes the classes-dex2jar.jar to some other folder.
I tried the following:

```
d2j-dex2jar %arg1% -o %arg2%
```

Here, arg1 is the path to classes.dex and arg2 is the folder where I wish to store the generated classes-dex2jar.jar file. (E:\new\)

Now, I am getting FileNotFoundException for the second argument. It says

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\new" (The filename, directory name,    
or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openOutputStream(FileUtils.java:77)
    at com.googlecode.dex2jar.v3.Dex2jar.to(Dex2jar.java:250)
    at com.googlecode.dex2jar.tools.Dex2jarCmd.doCommandLine(Dex2jarCmd.java
    :110)
    at com.googlecode.dex2jar.tools.BaseCmd.doMain(BaseCmd.java:174)
    at com.googlecode.dex2jar.tools.Dex2jarCmd.main(Dex2jarCmd.java:34)
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.io.FileOutputStream.open` - looks like you'are trying to open directory with FileOutputStream , which should be not possible.

Comment: java.io.FileOutputStream.open is not called by his code, but by the d2j-dex2jar tool.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing the folder as an argument, pass it the jar filename.

```
d2j-dex2jar classes.dex -o "E:\new\classes.jar"
```

Also make sure `E:\new` directory exists. Dex2jar does not create a new directory. Create a directory and then pass d2j-dex2jar the full path to the directory plus the jar file name you want.